# How to click on IE save option

Tags: vba, internet-explorer

I want to automate the SAVE on IE using VBA.

I have attached a snapshot of the save option:

[image: Save PopUp bar on IE]

I tried code below but it's showing error

> Object variable or with block not set.

```
Option Explicit

 Dim ie As InternetExplorer
    Dim h As LongPtr

Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "USER32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

Private Declare Function FindWindowEx Lib "USER32" Alias "FindWindowExA" (ByVal hWnd1 As Long, ByVal hWnd2 As Long, ByVal lpsz1 As String, ByVal lpsz2 As String) As Long

Sub Download()
    Dim o As IUIAutomation
    Dim e As IUIAutomationElement
    Set o = New CUIAutomation
    h = ie.hwnd
    h = FindWindowEx(h, 0, "Frame Notification Bar", vbNullString)
    If h = 0 Then Exit Sub

    Set e = o.ElementFromHandle(ByVal h)
    Dim iCnd As IUIAutomationCondition
    Set iCnd = o.CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_NamePropertyId, "Save")

    Dim Button As IUIAutomationElement
    Set Button = e.FindFirst(TreeScope_Subtree, iCnd)
    Dim InvokePattern As IUIAutomationInvokePattern
    Set InvokePattern = Button.GetCurrentPattern(UIA_InvokePatternId)
    InvokePattern.Invoke
End Sub
```

Comment: The “Open“, “Save” and “Cancel” buttons are Child windows  of the main window which is “File Download“. each one of those will have a `hWnd`, To find the child windows, use  `FindWindowEx`. All three buttons have the same class which is “ Button”. Try `FindWindow(vbNullString, "File Download")` work with `if statement <>`. - also Look for `API’s GetWindowText and GetWindowTextLength` and more or may be `URLDownloadToFile` can't remember :-( sry - this should be good info to get you started- Good luck

Comment: Hi 0m3r, the code compiled successfully for 4-5 times but after that it showing error of ambiguity, at  " h = ie.hwnd" and i go through whole code i haven't seen any duplicate variable.